# Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, windows, csv

Estoy intentando ingresar datos a una bd de MySQL desde un archivo .csv y al ejecutar esta líena de comandos:

```
load data infile 'C:\respaldo\respaldo.csv'
into table productos
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

Me sale este error:

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Investigando en internet, vi esta función estaba algo restringida por defecto y que se podía solucionar mediante la modificación de la línea `secure-file-priv =` en el archivo de configuración my.ini, algunos sugiriendo que se debía igualar a 1 y otros como una cadena vacía. Como sea, el caso es que no encuentro esa línea en el archivo de configuración, intenté agregársela en el apartado `mysqld` o `mysql` de las dos formas, tanto igualando a 1 como a cadena vacía y no funciona. En otros foros encontré que el problema se debía a que la variable `secure-file-priv` tenía el valor de la ruta C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data (eso se vé ejecutando el comando `SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv`) y que debía mover ahí el archivo .csv pero tampoco funciona.
No encuentro por ningún lado la línea `secure-file-priv`

¿Alguna idea? Soy nuevo en esto, uso MySQL 8.0 en Windows

Comment: pudiste solucionar el error. A mí me sale el mismo error. Y no encontré la solución
Saludos Gabriel